# How to Create Custom Design Time Error

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors

I want to create something in visual studio that will create a design time error if specified code is found within a project.

I have searched but was not able to locate anything.  Is this possible, if so can you supply either an example or link to an example.

Thank you

Comment: Define `in project` do you mean if source code is found in source code, that is redundant. Or do you mean if someone enters certain code into a form in the program?

Comment: I mean is certain source code is found in the solution, the display an error in the error list

Comment: You cannot look for certain errors, I mean you could write an if statement looking for a condition that would indicate said source code is present and in turn display an error but that is it.